# Excel: adding up execution time

Tags: excel

I'm measuring execution times of some applications and I would like to sum it up. The format of one cell is hh:mm:ss.miliseconds. E.g.

> 00:05:01.7822610

How to sum it up? Carefully, of course. I would like to put 60 seconds as 1 minute, 60 minutes as one hour etc. and get the result in the same format.

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest asking one question per post when they are unrelated ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is an answer to your first question**

Please post your second question in other post.

1) Format your input cells as text.

2) Convert them to seconds using the following formula. Suppose **A3** is your source cell:

```
=VALUE(MID(A3,1,2))*60*60+VALUE(MID(A3,4,2))*60)+ VALUE(MID(A3,7,2))+VALUE(MID(A3,10,7))/10000000
```

3) Operate with those numbers (add, for example)

4) Convert back to your original format using the following formula. Suppose **C3** is your source cell now:

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(INT(C3/3600),"00"),":",TEXT( INT( (C3-3600*INT(C3/3600))/60),"00"),":",TEXT( INT( (C3-60*INT(C3/60))),"00"),TEXT((C3-INT(C3)),".0000000") )
```

HTH!

Comment: Hm, I get the error, it doesn't work for me. But still, that means that I would have to use aditional column for converted values. Is it possible to do it without that?

Answer (score 1):

about the time.. you can use **Format Cells** as **hh:mm:ss.000**
and to sum it up you can experimenter with **[Date and Time Functions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/CH006252823.aspx)**

for the second question: put your data in cell **A1**, **B1**, **C1** and in **D1** write **=5*A1-2*B1-4*C1**

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I can format the cell as [h]:mm:ss.kk, but the sum doesn't work then. I've looked into all date and time functions, but I couldn't find any that recognizes miliseconds. About the other question, I will have hundreds of these values and it seems impossible to manualy separate them into different cells. That's why I've aksed for the function...